# Microsoft Access 2010 set all cells equal to somevalue

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

I have a table, and I want to set all the cells in the row "State_Abbr" = "MN"
How can I do this?

Comment: Is "State_Abbr" the field name or a value in a field?  Becuase if it is a value and you went to update all the cells then the value "State_abbr" would be overwritten.  If this is not the case, then see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State_Abbr sounds like a field name.  If that is the case then you will just need to do a simple sql update.  You should be able to go into the query editor, switch to sql and then type in what is below.  Remember to replace the section in brackets with your table name.

```
update [table name here] set state_abbr = "MN" where (state_abbr is null or state_abbr is not null)
```

Comment: What is the point of that `where (state_abbr is null or state_abbr is not null)` clause? It's extraneous.

Comment: I haven't used access in a long time and I couldn't remember if you left a where clause off did it match every record or threw an error so I put something in that would match everything.

Comment: your memory of how Access worked when you used it in the past is faulty. Access has never worked that way.